# Given that $B$ is a flat $A$-algebra, why is the following an exact sequence of $B$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, flatness

Given that $B$ is a flat $A$-algebra, why is the following an exact sequence of $B$-modules:

$M'\otimes_A B\rightarrow M\otimes_A B \rightarrow M''\otimes_A B \rightarrow 0$, $M$'s are $A$-modules and exact

So how do we view the individual tensor product as a $B$- module; What exactly is the ring action over $M$'s.

Cheers

Comment: The action of $B$ is given by $b\cdot (m\otimes b') = m\otimes (bb')$ where $b,b'\in B$.

Comment: Is $M' \to M \to M'' \to 0$ an exact sequence?